# How to read colon in python?

Tags: python, self-study

My course has the following statement.

```
a = np.array([[3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 6]])
```

> We select all columns of a matrix where the entry on row 1 is greater
> than the entry in row 0

```
a[:, a[1, :] > a[0, :]]
```

I am confused about the colon being in the first position to mean "select all columns" and the colon also being in the second position for  a[1, :]

Is there a better way to say it for an SQL programmer?

Comment: it is surprising but what shape is `a`?

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = a[1, :] > a[0, :]` takes the value `array([False,  True,  True])` as it finds columns for which, the values in the second line are larger than the values in the first line.

Since `x` has boolean values, `a[:, x]` will extract, across all rows (because the colon at the first dimension of the array), all the columns for which `x` takes the value `True`, in this case, the last two columns.

Comment: i.e From all rows, select the columns where the first entry is more than the zeroth entry.